# How to format and where to place the "thanks" section for websites in a book?

Tags: formatting, ebook, kindle

I just finished a "long" [short story](http://www.scribophile.com/authors/alexandro-chen/works/ghost-earthquake-part-1-of-3/). And I want to include a section where I thanks [Writers SE](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) for the writing advice and [Scribophile](http://www.scribophile.com/) for the critiques and feedback.

How is that properly done? What's the format and where should I place it? (Right now, the pages are like, page 1: book cover, page 2: copyright, page 3: the story...)

Comment: Your thank you notes should be in relation to the length of your text. I have never seen a short story with a thank you note. And I'm annoyed at the pages of thanks at the end of books. All I accept as a reader is the one short sentence *before* the text dedicating it, e.g., "To Joan". Why don't you thank the people were you got your help? No need to publish it in print. Think about someone reading about "Thank you to Laurem Ipsum and the guys at writers.SE" in a hundred years. Amateurish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end, after the story is finished, in a section called "Author's notes." You can list your thanks, your sources, and any other comments you want to make.

Answer (score 0):

This is the 'normal' layout of a book but there's a degree of flexibility.

- Half title – The book title. This page contains the title of the book, usually written in CAPITALS at the top of the first page. It’s the first page you see when opening the cover. Follow this with a 'section break (new page)' if you are using a frontispiece. If you are not using one then use a ‘section break (odd page).
- Frontispiece – (optional) A full page illustration on the verso of the half title and facing the title page.
- Title page – The title, subtitle, author and publisher of the book. May also include the year of publication and location of the author. This is always a right-hand page of a two page spread.
- Copyright page – On the verso of the title page and containing copyright notice, edition information, publication information, cataloguing data, legal notices, and the book’s ISBN number.
- Dedication - (optional) **This is where you would thank contributors**.
- Table of contents – (optional, especially in fiction) This should always start on a right hand (odd numbered) page.
- List of figures/tables – (optional)
- Epigraph – (optional) A quotation or poem. This may be placed on the verso of contents, list of figures, or facing chapter one. Epigraphs may also be placed at the start of each chapter.
- Forward – (optional) A short piece written by someone other than the author possibly explaining the context of the book.
- Preface – (optional) A short piece written by the author explaining the context of the book and how it came about.
- Prologue - (optional and often undesirable) Sets the scene for a fictional work and should be written in a character’s voice rather than the author’s voice.
- And finally! Chapter 1 – always starting on a right hand (odd) page.

At the end of the book put a 'From the Author' section - a good place to request reviews and detail other books.